# Using RegEx's in Multi-Channel Funnels in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, https, no-www

For some reason, I can't get my multichannel funnel which utilizes RegEx's in the path steps to function -- it keeps coming back with no data. There are a few variables which may be holding things up, but I can't figure out the origin of the problem, nor a solution. Here's the situation:

- The funnel is tracking conversions, defined as when a user completes 4 steps to signup
- Steps are not "required"
- Default URL is set to `https://example.com`
- There is a 302 redirect set up on our site that leads from `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`
- Within the funnel, steps switch from non-secure pages (unless browser is set to secure browsing), to secure pages once the user moves from the landing page to the second page of the sign-up process (account placeholder has been created)
- URL at that point contains the variable of publisher number within (but not at the end) the URL
- My RegEx's are all properly written as tested on rubular.com

Answer (score 1):

[This started as a comment since it's obviously not a proper answer, but got a bit overgrown.]
It's a semi-random stab(I've never had to set one of these up), but did you check that Rubular's output is actually compatible with whatever Analytics is expecting for the regex? There are a [few implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax) of Regex As Concept that aren't completely interchangeable.

Even then, sometimes a specific *application's* regex implementation isn't complete POSIX/PCRE/etc., so here's the [Analytics Regular Expressions](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034324) doc page. (Which unfortunately doesn't explicitly state you can *only* use those features, but let's assume for the moment.) That's actually a pretty small subset of what you might be able to do in Perl, for example. You might start by seeing if your regex has anything in it not listed on that page.